# Using requests or straight DynamoDB object to retrieve items from table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently working with the DynamoDB AWS API and just found two different ways of doing apparently the same thing, I was actually wondering if there is any performance or benefit in user one instead of another.

My current scenario is restricted to just a table, so I will be only manipulating that one without going any further.

Is there any benefit from using this (which I think that in my scenario is simpler that forming a request every single time I want to check key existence, and I can also have a fixed `Table` object to request any time I need to)...

```
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("my-table");
    table.getItem("sample");
```

... with this one?

```
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();

    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    key.put("Artist", new AttributeValue().withS("sample1"));
    key.put("SongTitle", new AttributeValue().withS("sample2"));

    GetItemRequest request = new GetItemRequest()
        .withTableName("my-table")
        .withKey(key);
```

I've taken the code from the actual examples in the AWS website.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKs.Interfaces.LowLevel.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIWorkingWithTables.html#JavaDocumentAPIListTables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` is more or less a light-weight wrapper around the DynamoDB client object. (You can see this by looking at its [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.java) on Guthub.) You can use whichever one you think makes your code the most readable and maintainable.